# Как сравнить массив по типу и значению ключей на основе первого массива?

Tags: php

Как сравнить массив `$arr2` массива на основе первого массива `$arr1`?

Ключи заранее незвестны.

К примеру если в массиве `$arr2` есть все ключи из массива `$arr1` и значения ключей тогоже типа то условие проходит проверку.

Ниже пример проверку не проходит

```
$arr1  = ['symbol' => 'EUR', 'sum' => 72.35, 'asset' => '1', 'active' => true];
$arr2 = ['symbol' => 'EUR', 'sum' => 73.21, 'asset' => '0'];

if ($arr1 === $arr2) {
  // совпадают
} else {
  // не совпадают
}
```

Ниже пример проверку проходит

```
$arr1  = ['symbol' => 'EUR', 'sum' => 74.25, 'asset' => 1, 'active' => true];
$arr2 = ['symbol' => 'EUR', 'sum' => 74.25, 'asset' => 1];

if ($arr1 === $arr2) {
  // совпадают
} else {
  // не совпадают
}
```

Comment: почему во втором случае проверку проходит, если нет одного ключа?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский в `$arr1`  может выть любое количество ключей. Нужно проверить `$arr2` главное чтобы в нем были все ключи которые есть в `$arr1` и значения все совпадают

Comment: ну тогда бери либо https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-intersect-assoc.php  либо https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-diff-assoc.php  и всё ... сравнивай результат с длиной второго массива......

Answer (score 0):

Я при подобных задачах использую ф-ю `array_reduce()`:

```
<?php
    $res =
        array_reduce(
            array_keys($arr2),
            function($nonce, $key) use ($arr1, $arr2) {
                return $nonce && gettype($arr1[$key]) === gettype($arr2[$key]);
            },
            true
        );
?>
```

Проходим по всем ключам массива arr2 и сравниваем, для каждого, типы значений в обоих массивах. Результат - значение типа boolean

[ПЕСОЧНИЦА](https://onlinephp.io/c/543ff)